# Why do I get a seg fault when assigning a string pointer to a string pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

Consider the following simplified code:

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
    int numberB;
    std::string strA;
} StructA;

typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
    int numberB;
    std::string strB;
} StructB;

char *ExampleClass::getBuffer(void){
  char* mBuf;
  int offset = 10;
  return mBuf+offset;
 }

void ExampleClass::ExampleFunction(StructA *A){
    StructB *B = (StructB *)getBuffer();
    B->numberB = A->numberA;
    B->strB = A->strA;
    return;
    }
```

There is a lot of code not shown here intentionally, but I believe the root of my question do be demonstrated: Why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to assign B->strB = A->strA?

Thanks

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`B->numberB = ...`).

Comment: sorry, in the real case the pointer is initialized, I've updated the example to show how this actually gets used.  The int field gets assigned properly when debugging.  The string is what causes the segfault

Comment: @DanielKlisiewicz you cannot skip the construction of `string` (or the whole `struct`) .

Comment: thanks @appleapple.  In the getBuffer function, I construct a (char*), which I then cast to a (B*).  Is this not permitted? It seems like the compiler doesn't complain.  It may sound silly, but how do I construct the string field if I get the entire structure from casting from a (char*)?

Comment: What you want here is not feasible with casting a char* to your struct type. It looks like you're trying to do (de-)serialization (which is the keyword you should be searching for). The way you do it might work with POD types, but definitely not with types like `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getBuffer()`, `mBuf` is *uninitialized*, but you add `offset` to it, so the pointer being `return`'ed is *indeterminate*. It certainly does not point at a valid `StructB` object, which is why the subsequent code in `ExampleFunction()` crashes when accessing `B`'s members. Technically, this is **undefined behavior**, so *anything* can happen, a crash is not guaranteed.

But, even if `mBuf` were initialized to a valid `char[]` buffer large enough to hold a `StructB` object, there is still no `StructB` object actually being constructed in this code, thus `B->numberB` and `B->strA` are not valid objects.

`getBuffer()` would need to do something more like this:

```cpp
char* ExampleClass::getBuffer(){
    char* mBuf = ...; // point to some char[] buffer that is at
                      // least 10+sizeof(StructB) in size, and
                      // isn't deallocated when getBuffer exits...
    int offset = 10;
    new(mBuf+offset) StructB;
    return mBuf+offset;
}

void ExampleClass::ExampleFunction(StructA *A){
    StructB *B = (StructB *)getBuffer();
    B->numberB = A->numberA;
    B->strB = A->strA;
    B->~StructB();
}
```

Or else, `ExampleFunction()` would need to do this instead:

```cpp
char* ExampleClass::getBuffer(){
    char* mBuf = ...; // point to some char[] buffer that is at
                      // least 10+sizeof(StructB) in size, and
                      // isn't deallocated when getBuffer exits...
    int offset = 10;
    return mBuf+offset;
}

void ExampleClass::ExampleFunction(StructA *A){
    StructB *B = new(getBuffer()) StructB;
    B->numberB = A->numberA;
    B->strB = A->strA;
    B->~StructB();
}
```

Comment: This was an awesome answer.  Thank you for being detailed and respectful.